# Error - uninitialized constant Project::Ticket

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]



  def show
  end

  def set_ticket
    @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.for(current_user).find(params[:project_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:alert] = "The project you were looking " +"for could not be found."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

project's template- show.html.erb

```
<% @project.tickets.each do |ticket| %> 
  <li>
    #<%= ticket.id %> - <%= link_to ticket.title, [@project, ticket] %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I am getting error: `uninitialized constant Project::Ticket` the first line of show template

This is in my routes file

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tickets
end
```

**backtrace**

> ```
> 'Started GET "/projects/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 21:47:37 +0530
> Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
> Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
> ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."i
> d" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
> ←[1m←[36mProject Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHE
> RE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", "6"]]
> ←[1m←[35mPermission Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "permissions".* FROM "permissions
> " WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 4]]
> Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/application (19.0ms)
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Project::Ticket):
> 11: <% end %>
> 12:
> 13: <ul id='tickets'>
> 14: <% @project.tickets.each do |ticket| %>
> 15: <li>
> 16: #<%= ticket.id %> - <%= link_to ticket.title, [@project, ticket] %>
> 17: </li>
> app/views/projects/show.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__106
> 1934704_22827060'
>
>
> Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispa
> tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
> Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispa
> tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
> Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispa
> tch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (35.0m
> s)'
> ```
>
> full trace-
>
> ```
> activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:125:in `compute_type' activerecord (4.0.1)
> ```
>
> lib/active_record/reflection.rb:178:in `klass' activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:123:in`klass'
>   activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:37:in
>   `reader' activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in`tickets'
>   app/views/projects/show.html.erb:14:in
>   `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__1061934704_22827060' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in`block in render'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in`
>   render' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels)
>   in render_template' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in`block in
>   instrument' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in`instrument'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in
>   `block in render_template' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in`
>   render_with_layout' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in`
>   render' actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in
>   `render_template' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in`render' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in`
>   _render_template' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in`
>   render_to_body' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in`render'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in
>   `render' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in`block (2 levels)
>   in render' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in`realtime' activesupport
>   (4.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in`block in
>   render' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in
>   `cleanup_view_runtime' activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in`
>   cleanup_view_runtime' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
>   actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in`default_render'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in
>   `send_action' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in
>   `_run__975686654__process_action__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in
>   process_action' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`
>   instrument' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in`process_action'
>   activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in
>   `dispatch' actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in`
>   block in action' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in`
>   block in call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in`
>   call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in
>   `call' activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in`
>   _run__388525736__call__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties
>   (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged' railties (4.0.1)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in`call' rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' railties (4.0.1)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call' railties (4.0.1)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in
>   start_thread'

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy

has_many :permissions, as: :thing
scope :viewable_by, ->(user) do
    joins(:permissions).where(permissions: { action: "view",
        user_id: user.id })
end

  scope :for, ->(user) do
    user.admin? ? Project.all : Project.viewable_by(user)
  end
  validates :name, presence: true

 end
```

Comment: Can you tell the exact location of the error and add that line to the question?

Comment: i wrote it that error is on the first line of show template that is -<% @project.tickets.each do |ticket| %>

Comment: Can you actually show the backtrace?

Comment: Sorry m new here... What is backtrace?

Comment: The complete exception that gets displayed on screen. all the lines shows where the exception originated and how it propagated.

Comment: @dips - usually when you get an error, you'll have a page like [this](http://elia.schito.me/tumblr_files/rails-backtrace-links.png). Getting the full "Application Trace" is usually pretty helpful. Sometimes you need to see the "Full Trace" but that is usually when you have problems with gems.

Comment: Thankyou.. I editted  my question. please have a look

Comment: Can you add Full trace? when, you click on it, you get complete error trace. Your error is not originating at view level. Its probably coming from some model.

Comment: Thankyou RyanJM for the explanation.

Comment: Can you show your Project model? It's likely to be the culprit

Comment: I added the full trace also...... please have a look

Comment: Added project model also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some model which Rails is not able to pluralize/singularize correctly in your case. Thus, it is not able to fetch the class name from associations.

Specify the associations along with classnames.

```
has_many :tickets, class_name: Ticket, dependent: :destroy
```

Do similar on the other side `belongs_to` of the association.

As suggested in another answer, you must have a `Ticket` model. If this is correctly present, then you should not have to set `class_name` in this case.

Comment: I had Ticket model=> 'class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :project'

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The previous answer was incorrect.

According to the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) what you have setup should work.

Have you checked to make sure that `@project = Project.for(current_user).find(params[:project_id])` works? It might be better to do an if statement to check to see if `@project` exists rather than do the `rescue`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a Ticket model? This is the error you'd get if the model Ticket doesn't exist. Maybe you have named it something different. Keep in mind that [the class name is inferred from the name of the association](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

Comment: class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
has_many :assets
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }


end

Comment: this was my ticket model ...anyway it worked by giving the class name in associations which nerve suggested. thankyou :)